# ambiguous access error in c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I got an error `ambiguous access mg`. but mg is only protected and inherited using public access. why is it so? throw some light please. Thanks for your time !

```
class A{    
    protected:    
        int mg; 
        static int ms; 
};    

class B : public A{    
    protected:    
        using A::ms;  
};    

class C : public A, public B{    
    public:    
        void fn(){  
            cout << mg; 
            cout << ms;
        }  
};  

int A::ms = 0;

int main(){    
    C c; 
    c .fn(); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly derive C from A?  Perhaps this example is too trimmed-down to be of use.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, you have two copies of the base class `A` in class `C`, as `B` already derives from `A`.  This also gives a base class of `A` in `C`:

```
class C : public B{    
   public:    
    void fn(){  
    cout << mg; 
    cout << ms;
    }  
 };
```

This problem is known as the "diamond of death" and is used to explain the danger of multiple inheritance.  Except here it has been reduced to a "triangle of death."

Answer (score 2):

in `C`, `A::mg` can refer to the one inherited from `A`, or to the one inherited from `B` because `B` inherits `A`. So the call is ambiguous : which one do you really refer to ?

Using virtual inheritance *can* solve this problem. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379053/diamond-inheritance-c) which is on a problem really similar than yours : the diamond inheritance.

Comment: You've identified the problem, but virtual inheritance is most likely not an appropriate solution.

Comment: Agree, but I just cited virtual inheritance as a possible solution, not the only one solution.