# How to use interface in a base-class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interface

considering following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct ITimer {
    virtual void createTimer() = 0;
};
class A : public ITimer
{
    public:
        void showA() {
            printf("showA\n");
            createTimer();
        }
};

class B : public ITimer
{
    public:
        void showB() {
            printf("showB\n");
        }
        void createTimer() {
            printf("createTimer");
        }
};

class C: public A, public B
{
    public:
        void test() {
            showA();
            showB();
        }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.test();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to use interface ITimer in class A, but the method is implemented in class B. So I inherited the interface in A, but the compiler is not happy with it:

```
test.cc
test.cc(38) : error C2259: 'C' : cannot instantiate abstract class
        due to following members:
        'void ITimer::createTimer(void)' : is abstract
        test.cc(5) : see declaration of 'ITimer::createTimer'
```

How could I use the interface in baseclass A while its method is implemented in class B.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does `A` inherit `ITimer`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Nawaz: `I need to use interface ITimer in class A, but the method is implemented in class B. So I inherited the interface in A, `

Comment: @Saravanan: both of gcc and msvc...

Comment: Inheritance is the base-class of all evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance is the base-class of all evil.

`A` nor `B` *are* `ITimer`s

A doesn't even implement the pure virtual, so it cannot be instantiated. Therefore, inheriting from `A` makes `C` *abstract* too (cannot be instantiated).

You don't want to use inheritance here. See

- [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) ("is-a" rule)

---

In this case, the dreaded *diamond-of-death hierarchy* could be fixed by adding `virtual`:

```
class A : public virtual ITimer
//...
class B : public virtual ITimer
```

See it **[Live on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/ZTNvne)**. I don't recommend this, though. Consider fixing the design.

See also [Diamond inheritance (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379053/diamond-inheritance-c/379713#379713)