# c++: How do you access base class calls in multiple/multilevel inheritance from within the class?

Tags: c++

This is the simplified code:

```
class a
{
public:
    void func( void )
    {
        //Want to call this
    }
    int avar;
};

class b : public a
{
public:
    void func( void )
    {
    }
};

class c : public a
{
public:
    void func( void )
    {
    }
};

class d : public b, public c
{
public:
    void d1()
    {
        //b::a::avar;
        //c::a::avar;
        //b::a::func();
        //c::a::func();
    }
};
```

How do you properly qualify a call to access the members of both instances of the subclass a, the things I've tried leads to a 'a is an ambiguous base of d' error.  Same question if the hierarchy was one more class deep or if a class template was involved.  I'm not looking for a virtual base.

Comment: This is known as diamond inheritance problem. check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379053/diamond-inheritance-c) and [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)

Comment: Not in a place to try it, but how about `((c*)this)->avar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the immediate base class functions using the explicit calls.

```
void d1()
{
    b::func();
    c::func();
}
```

You can call `a::func` from `b::func` similarly.

```
class b : public a
{
public:
    void func( void )
    {
       a::func();
    }
};
```

If you also want to access the member `a::var` and call `a::func` directly from `d::d1`, you can use:

```
void d1()
{
    b* bPtr = this;
    bPtr->avar;        // Access the avar from the b side of the inheritance.
    bPtr->a::func();   // Call a::func() from the b side of the inheritance

    c* cPtr = this;
    cPtr->avar;        // Access the avar from the c side of the inheritance.
    cPtr->a::func();   // Call a::func() from the c side of the inheritance
}
```

Comment: I've never seen `bPtr->a::func();` syntax before.  does `this->b::a::func()` work?

Comment: This one worked, except in the form of static_cast<b*>(this)->a::func();  Thanks!